# Can anyone teach/guide me how to get string length of a list button in Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

Can anyone teach/guide me how to get string length of a list button in Qml? I am in need of list button text's length/width in characters instead pixelWidth.

Comment: what is *list button* here? Please provide some code explaining your problem.

Comment: Please find code at below link:
http://cpp.sh/7canl

Comment: What if someone wants to run this code? What exactly do you want to get? What did you already try? What was an error/unexpected behavior? If you really want to get an answer  please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article before asking a question.

Comment: @folibis

Hi folibis,

I am really sorry for the incomplete info. I just wanted to know how many characters(maximum) can be fit into my list button where button width(ListDifferentButtons) is list.width (which is 500 pixels) and fontPixelsize is 50.  I have shared only snapshot of my code, it will not run.

I will appreciate if you could suggest any way or algorithm or anything to convert pixel width into string/character width rest i will take care :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's say your question was:

> How can I get a string length with specified font fits a button with
> specified size?

*In this case the answer could be:*

I think you should not treat a string like a set of chars. A font could be fixed-size (Monospaced), where all the characters have the same width or variable-width where the letters have different widths. So pixel width of string `"iii"` could be differ from string `"www"` although both of them have 3 characters. Therefore, I guess the best practice is to trim entire string at position depending on the needed width. You can use [FontMetrics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html), for example:

```
Button {
    id: btn
    width: 300
    text: ""
    font.pixelSize: 50
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var str = "Some long long long long long string";
        var  btnString = fnt.elidedText(str,Qt.ElideNone, btn.width);
        btn.text = btnString;
    }
}
FontMetrics {
    id: fnt
    font: btn.font
}
```

Comment: Thanks folibis.
I will check this and then update you.